# Smoothing hx711 readings with atmega328

Tags: arduino-uno

I am making a 50kg weighing scale using **HX711 ADC**. My project includes **Atmega328** along with **74HC595** for driving 5 7segment displays(multiplexed). I am using the function `scale.get_units()`to fetch the data and the values are very well displayed on the 7segments. The problem I am facing is the readings on the 5th digit (right most 1's) are unstable. Now, if I use `scale.read_average(5)`, **my display scanning gets slow**. I was wondering if there is a way to average the readings in a loop like the conventional way. I tried it but with no luck! It keeps showing random added numbers. Any help would be highly appriciated. Below is the code inside the loop. Let me know if full code is needed. Thanx in advance!

```cpp
if (scale.is_ready()) {
    weight = scale.get_units();
    finalWeight = weight * 1000;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++) {
    sum += finalWeight;
}
average = sum / 10;
if (average < 0) {
    break_number(0);
} else {
    break_number(average);
}
display_number();
delay(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this code:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++) {
    sum += finalWeight;
}
average = sum / 10;
```

does not average multiple readings. Instead, it takes the single reading
stored in `finalWeight`, multiplies it by ten (by means of successive
additions), then divides it by ten to get back the same value.

If you want to reduce the noise, you have to take multiple readings and
average them. The reading-taking code must thus be inside the loop. A
simple option may be like this:

```cpp
void loop() {
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        while (!scale.is_ready()) {}  // wait for the scale to be ready
        sum += scale.get_units();
    }
    weight = sum / 10;  // compute the average
    display(weight);    // and display it
}
```

Note that I have simplified things a bit by removing the scaling
factors. You can take this as simple inspiration and adapt to your
specific needs.

The code above has one problem though: as the code is blocking while
waiting for the scale to be ready, the display is not refreshed. You
could fix this by explicitly refreshing the display within the waiting
loop:

```cpp
void loop() {
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        while (!scale.is_ready()) {  // wait...
            display(weight);         // ...while refreshing the display
        }
        sum += scale.get_units();
    }
    weight = sum / 10;
    display(weight);
}
```

This should work, but I would however suggest instead a third approach:
write *non-blocking code*. This is code that never blocks: instead, if
something can be done *right now*, it does it. If not, it moves along:

```cpp
void loop() {
    if (scale.is_ready()) {  // if something useful can be done NOW:
        sum += scale.get_units();
        count++;
        if (count >= 10) {
            weight = sum / count;  // update the value to be displayed
            sum = 0;               // reset the averaging variables
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    display(weight);  // unconditionally refresh the display
}
```

This way, your `loop()` always runs fast, and you can add code that will
not be blocked by the stuff you wrote earlier.

**Edit**: As suggested by chrisl in a comment, a moving average may
better serve your needs. I would try the exponentially-weighted version,
as it is lightweight and simpler to implement. You may want to explore
this path.

Comment: In addition: Here a moving average might be a good choice, like in the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67208086/how-can-i-calculate-a-moving-average-in-arduino)

Comment: Thanx a lot!! I will try it.